# cloud pickle current class with all its variable values

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

I am having sample program with file name myAutocomplete.py and want to return instance of class

```
import cloudpickle


class Autocomplete(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = " Test String "

    def assign_value(self):
        self.test = "Hello"
        return self.test

    def get_value(self):
        return self.test

    @staticmethod
    def save(path):
        with open(path, "wb") as f:
            cloudpickle.dump(Autocomplete, f)

    @staticmethod
    def load(path):
        with open(path, "rb") as f:
            test = cloudpickle.load(f)
        return test
```

and another file with name main.py

```
from myAutocomplete import Autocomplete

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testobj = Autocomplete()
    testobj.assign_value()
    testobj.save("test.pkl")
    test = testobj.load("test.pkl")
    print(test().get_value())
```

i expecting output as

```
 "Hello"
```

but i am getting output as

```
"Test String"
```

plz help

Comment: There is a difference between class `Autocomplete` and object `Autocomplete()`. You create and modify object. Then you save class. Then you load class and create new object. So you have to modify this new object or save and load object instead of class.

Comment: @Poolka can you plz modify the code, as i am not getting what you just said

Comment: Modification depends on your goal. For example, you may save object instead of class - you may turn static `save(path)` method into a regular class method `save(self, path)` and save object instead of class `cloudpickle.dump(self, f)`.

Comment: @Poolka ok got it, thanku